# Is there a way to store 4-byte UTF-8 encoded characters from a file as two characters in Python?

Tags: python, file, utf-8, utf-16

My understanding of encoding/decoding isn't the best so apologies if any of this is confusing:

I'm modding a Javascript app. It searches an index file to find a word's index then accesses the word's entry in the dictionary file using its index. So if the index for the word is 100, then the word's definition appears at dict[100]. The files are loaded in the Javascript app into variables using response.text(). This seems to render 4-byte utf-8 encoded characters as two separate characters. For instance:  and  are four bytes in utf-8 so I think they're appearing as �� (like they do in cmd). The current indices account for this, but since I'm updating the entries in the dictionary, I need to update the indices. Is there a way in Python to decode 4-byte utf-8 encoded characters as two characters? My current solution is to read the old_index and old_dict files in Python and manually add an extra character whenever the index fails to find the entry. I'm suspecting I need to switch languages for a more elegant solution.

---

EDIT: I feel like explaining my goal made this confusing. The crux of the matter is I'm trying to find a way to count 4-byte utf-8 encoded characters twice. This can probably be done by going character by character and checking the size of its encoding in utf-8.

```
 with open(r"data\dict.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
     dict = f.read()
 for char in dict:
    byteArray = char.encode("utf-8")
    if len(byteArray) == 4:
       idx += 2
    else:
       idx += 1
```

Comment: That should be `... "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:`. Did you just make a typo here?

Comment: Do you know what a *surrogate pair* is? I notice you've tagged the question as `utf-16`; where exactly does that factor in to your problem? Also, I don't understand why you're telling us about a Javascript app (I assume you can't just modify that one). But to be clear, the file is encoded in UTF-8, and you want to *detect whether* a given character requires a surrogate pair to be represented in UTF-16?

Comment: The file is encoded in utf-8 (as far as I know). My friend was suggesting it could be utf-16 string-related hence including the tag. They thought the request.text() loaded utf16 strings and that's why if a character required four bytes for its utf-8 encoding it would count as two characters. I'm not sure though. I'm not at all knowledgeable on character encodings, and I don't know what a surrogate pair is. I don't understand why four-byte characters are being rendered as �� by some applications, but as a result, I need to count them as two characters. My code should work for this purpose.

Comment: Beware of [CESU-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CESU-8) when converting between UTF-8 and/or UTF-16 and/or UTF-32.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unicode characters with code point greater than or equal to 0x10000 have 4-byte representations in utf-8.

[Wikipedia utf-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)

So:

```
with open(r"data\dict.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    s = f.read()
idx = 0
for char in s:
    idx += 2 if ord(char) >= 0x10000 else 1
```

I hope that this code is sufficiently "elegant" to justify the use of Python :-)

I changed the variable name from "dict" to "s" since "dict" is the name of a built-in type.

Comment: Still don't quite understand *why* code points greater than or equal to 0x10000 are rendered as two characters by cmd and Javascript's request.text(), but I'll read more into character encoding after I finish the project :)

Comment: It's because numbers this large do not fit in a single 32-bit number (that 1 digit is the 33rd bit). Unicode originally went up to 32 bits, and the unicode implementation in cmd and javascript has not been extended to handle the additional complexity. So what you see in cmd and javascript is broken handling of unicode; if these are legacy files and your application does not need to be backward-compatible (except for reading them in once), you should fix the problem and handle these as a single character.

Comment: @metzkorn Note: Javascript is old and developed when unicode had just 16bit characters. Now, if you look carefully at JavaSript documentation, you see that many functions referrers to *Code Unit* when they need two "characters". (and so you may have functions which works on Code Units, and some in Code Points). Unfortunately it is impossible to deprecate things in JS, and nobody will follow it anyway.